# Hibernate Many to Many and JSON serialization

Tags: java, json, hibernate, serialization, many-to-many

I'm using `Hybernate` to persist some beans that have a Many-To-Many relationship. Here are the two beans:

**Email.java**

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Email.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Email e")
public class Email implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //... other fields ...

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to Pratica
    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "email_pratica", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "fk_email_id")
    }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "fk_pratica_id")
    })
    private List<Pratica> pratiche;

    public List<Pratica> getPratiche() {
        return this.pratiche;
    }

    public void setPratiche(List<Pratica> pratiche) {
        this.pratiche = pratiche;
    }

}
```

**Pratica.java**

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Pratica.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Pratica p")
public class Pratica extends AtstTable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //... other fields ...

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to Email
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "pratiche", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Email> emails;

    public List<Email> getEmails() {
        return this.emails;
    }

    public void setEmails(List<Email> emails) {
        this.emails = emails;
    }

}
```

This works correctly, however the problem is that I then need to serialize/deserialize these beans using `JSON`. Doing this causes an infinite recursion, since each object `Email` tries to serialize all of its objects `Pratica`, which in turn try to serialize all their `Email`s and so on, until a `StackOverflow` exception occours.

I've searched online and here on SO, and I've found several solutions to this problem, however none of them work or are applicable, due to the configuration of my project. In particular, here's what I've tried:

**Solution 1: using `@JsonManagedReference` / `@JsonBackReference`**

This seems to be the most suggested solution. However, this only works (as far as I can tell) for One-To-Many or Many-To-One relationships, since the `@JsonBackReference` annotation does not support collections (Lists, Arrays, Sets, etc.). Or at least, this is what the documentation says and when trying I got an exception that seems to confirm this. I've found a couple of examples online that use this annotation on a List, but for me it didn't work. If anyone has any clue on this, please elaborate.

**Solution 2: do not persist one side of the relationship using `@JsonIgnore`**

Adding `@JsonIgnore` to one of the fields, like this:

```
@ManyToMany()
@JoinTable(name = "email_pratica", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_email_id")
}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_pratica_id")
})
@JsonIgnore
private List<Pratica> pratiche;
```

breaks the infinite loop, and thus works. It would also suit me, since I don't really need the list of `Pratica` on the `Email` objects, I never use it.
However, this introduces another big problem: whenever I persist the object back to the database the list of Pratica will be empty (since it was lost during `JSON` serialization), and thus Hibernate will delete the association record from my Join Table.

**Solution 3: using `@JsonIdentityInfo`**
This solution needs `Jackson 2.x`, but unfortunately, due to restrictions on the server that are beyond my control, I can only use the version of Jackson provided by `RESTeasy` (`resteasy-jackson-provider 2.3.6`), which provides a subset of `Jackson 1.x`

**Solution 4: using a custom serializer/deserializer**
See solution 3. Even tho the `@JsonSerialize`/`@JsonDeserialize` annotations are included in `Jackson 1.1`, it seems they're not included in the version provided by RESTeasy, or at least the compiler can't find the references, so I assume this is the case.

So, after all this... is there a clean solution to this problem with the restrictions I have? Can it be done in a non-hacky way? And if it can't, what is the "less messy" non-hacky way?

Comment: Looks like the only way for you is if with `@JsonIgnore` on one side, and when persisting/updating you'd have to manually (re)connect them. Especially, since you can't update to a newer version that might support `@JsonBackReference` on collections (I haven't checked on that, but it's a good idea). The problem arises from the fact that JSON is not a format that naturally supports internal references.

Comment: @coladict: yep, that's what I'm doing currently. I posted the question to see if there is some other, cleaner method.

Answer (score -2):

You're mixing database objects with json, that's in my opinion the main problem, the main design flaw.

When you want to serialize your data with something other than json, you have to change your persistency layer. If you want to change your persistency layer, you have to change your json stuff, too.

And worse: Let's say you want to unit test your presentation layer - assuming you use json in your frontend - how are you going to do that, without your persistency layer?

So my answer is: Separate your concerns, decouple json from persistency.

Comment: I'm not using JSON explicitly, that was just to not overcomplicate things in the question. My actual setup is this: I have a backend server that persists  the db objects using hibernate, these objects are then sent to the frontend via a REST webservice. This webservice is implemented using restEasy and uses JSON (internally) to serialize/deserialize the objects passing through. Unfortunately, this is the one aspect of the architecture I CAN'T change.

Comment: Same answer in other words: Your presentation layer needs your persistency types, to do its job. Your persistency layer needs annotations from your presentation layer, not even to make it self work, but to make the presentation layer work. Both can not work independently. You have bidirectional dependency between your components. Change any technology stack of your software, touch and test every piece of code of your software. Lose coupling, high cohesion, I didn't invent those terms ;)

Comment: The annotations are not "from the presentation layer", they are in the backend, on the DB objects. I feel like you're missing the point, which is: objects with this kind of relationship do not persist properly in JSON without some workaround. This is well documented (search online) and has known solutions, that however have failed due to the old version of some libraries I'm forced to work with. Your "answer" basically comes down to "redesign the entire project to do something different", which I already told you is not possible, due to existing dependencies. It's not helpful at all.

Comment: That's what I meant: On the DB types, there are json-annotations to serialize them through your rest-service - that's like have hibernate annotations on a rest service. I'd recommend to map your db types to your own types, annotate them and let them be returned by the rest service. And my opinion: The problem is well documented, because people do not follow the 'easy as possible, but not easier' rule - that's why I answered in the first place: "I can annotate here, and everything magically works. Is it good? Well, the next poor fella can handle it." .. and look who we have here ;)

Comment: I agree that using two different types would be the best solution, but unfortunately there are existing dependencies on this project that mean I can't change that part... that's why I was searching for a workaround. Thanks for your insight.